# iOS Push通知 Distribution時のみ届かない

Tags: ios, php, push-notification

iOSでDistribution時にPush通知が届きません。

下記、状況でございます。

・サーバサイドはApnsPHP(https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP) を使用

・Development環境では届く

・Distribution環境では届かない

・試しにgrowthpush(https://growthpush.com) を使いDistributionでPushを送ると届く。なので、app証明書,push証明書,アプリ設定は問題ないと思ってます。

・ApnsPHPは本番時はENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTIONに設定している。コードは下記です。

```
$push = new ApnsPHP_Push(
ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION,
<CERTIFICATES_FILE>
);
```

・ApnsPHP_PushのsetRootCertificationAuthorityには開発と本番で同じものを使用

・Push送信時のログに下記が残る

```
STATUS: Sending message ID 1 [custom identifier: <数字のID>] (1/3): 129 bytes.
```

・push通知を送るデバイスは１回のプッシュで1台です。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: push通知の証明書はgrowth pushは.p12で、ApnsPHPは.p12を変換した.pemでしたので、このあたりの違いがあります。